# How can I find what version of TYPO3 the database is set to work with just from a database field?

Tags: mysql, typo3

Is there a database field that I can look up to find what version of TYPO3 the database it is set to work with?

Backstory: I'm trying to analyze an old database but don't have the file system now and need to know what the last version of TYPO3 it was operating.

Answer (score 2):

There is no field with the exact version number.
Within limits you can analyze the tables and fields to get hints what version it could be.

Example:
If there is a table `sys_file` you have a system with FAL, which was invented with 6.0

If there is a field `tt_content.media` this could be the effect of `ext:fluid_styled_content` introduced with 6.2(?), later (8?) it was changed to `tt_content.assets`

Other hints may be the existence of single fields or the exact declaration of fields. from time to time the size of different fields were changed. But that also could be individual extensions, which modified the default values for this special installation.

The same goes for extensions: you can identify some extensions by their tables which starts with `tx_extensionname`, here you also may identify the version of the extension  by tables and fields.

Other hints can come from field content. In the table `tt_content` you can find which kind of CE were on the pages. In the field `tt_content.CType` you have the type of elements, in `tt_content.list_type` you find the plugins.

For exacter identification you need to compare the field declaration of the core with the existing data structure.